# Understand linux bridge tunneling configuration

Tags: linux, vpn, bridge, tunneling, tap

I have a VPN software that creates a tap device connected to a bridge:

```
$ brctl show vpnbr
  bridge name   bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
  vpnbr     8000.6630fabc3f2b   yes     tnl-2c5a50e

$ brctl showmacs vpnbr
  port no   mac addr        is local?   ageing timer
    1   66:30:fa:bc:3f:2b   yes        0.00
```

What is a logic behind connecting single TAP to a bridge?
I would expect multiple ports to be connected to the bridge.
Why to use a bridge in a first place?

Comment: What exactly this software is? It looks like a configuration mistake.

Comment: It's a VPN software. The configuration isn't a mistake. The tunnel works. Maybe it's related to NAT translation in some way?

Comment: What VPN software is this?